# Como pegar a página atual de um dataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery-datatables, datatable

Como salvar em uma variável php a página atual de uma tabela usando o plugin dataTable?
Por exemplo: se estou na página dois a variável deve receber 2, se estiver na página 3 a variável deve receber 3 e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Lucas, nos mostre o que você já tentou fazer, dificilmente alguém irá fazer o trabalho pra você.

Comment: Não quero que façam pra mim, só quero saber a função do plugin dataTable que retorna o número da página.

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma metodo chamado Page no DataTable que retorna um inteiro com o valor da página atual, não sei bem como você está aplicando isto então não tem como detalhar em codigo a sua aplicabilidade, mas acho que este link abaixo irá te ajudar.

[Link page datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page())

Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição.

Comment: Valeu Luiz Ferndando, é isto que preciso, mas quero salvar o que retornar do metodo Page em uma variável php, será que é possível? segue abaixo o script do que alterei no dataTable        <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable( {
        "language": {
   "paginate":{
            "previous": "Anterior",
            "next": "Próximo"
   }  
  }
    } );
 } ); 
 $.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "searching": false,
    "ordering": false,
 "pagingType": "simple",
 "info": false,
 "pageLength": 4,
 "lengthChange": false
 } );
 </script>

Comment: Acredito que seria alguma coisa mais ou menos assim: var pagina = Page(); mas não to conseguindo, a sintaxe deve ser um pouco diferente

Comment: fiz isso: var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
          var pagina = table.page.info();                                                        e ai dou um echo na variavel pagina onde quero que ela apareça, mas está dando erro de variavel indefinida, sabe como posso resolver?

Answer (score -1):

Esse link deve te ajudar: https://blog.naun.com.br/2020/02/como-obter-o-numero-da-pagina-atual-com.html

Testei e funciona, verifica se atende as suas necessidades.

### Atualização:

Desta forma funciona melhor, pois ao clicar no botão do número da página o código informa qual a página que abriu:

```
var tabela = $('#ID_DA_TABELA').DataTable();
tabela.on('draw', function () {
    var info = tabela.page.info();
    alert('Pg. atual: '+(info.page+1));; //Informa via alert qual a página
});
```

Fonte: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/67279/how-to-show-current-page-number-in-different-place-in-a-webpage#Comment_188005

> Para as duas opções, não precisa de plug-in.